# How to track real-time input value to submit to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am relatively new to front.

I managed to make my table dynamic which becomes textarea when clicked and back to static table cell when lose the focus.

What I want to do here is sending the value every time it loses focus.
It does with Ajax, but the value in clicked cell is always disappearing when loses control. it happens at any cell.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<br>
<h2>English lines are under here</h2>
<h5>Click each row to modify</h5>
<br>
<table id="btable" class="bg-light table table-hover">
    <th class= "text-center">No</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Word</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Dialogue</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Practice</th>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="engboardVO">
    <tr>
        <td class="bid" data-name="bid">${engboardVO.bid}</td>
        <td class="word" data-name="word" data-editable>${engboardVO.word}</td>
        <td class="dialogue" data-name="dialogue" data-editable>${engboardVO.dialogue}</td>
        <td class="practice" data-name="practice" data-editable>${engboardVO.practice}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Script

```
$("table").on("click", "[data-editable]", function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var str = $el.text();
    console.log(str);
    var $input = $('<textarea rows=5 style="width:500px"/>').val( str );
    $el.html($input);
    $input.focus();
    var field_name = $el.attr('data-name');
    var save = function(bid, newWord, newDialogue, newPractice){
        var $td = $input.val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "/tight",
            data : JSON.stringify({
                bid : bid,
                word : newWord,
                dialogue : newDialogue,
                practice : newPractice
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(msg){
                if (msg["status"] == 'success'){
                    $input.replaceWith($td);
                } else {
                    alert("Fail");
                    $input.replaceWith($el);
                }
            },
            error : function(msg) {
                alert("ajax fail to get data from server");
            }
        });
    };
    $($input).blur(function(){
        var bid = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.bid').text();
        var newWord = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.word').text();
        var newDialogue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.dialogue').text();
        var newPractice = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.practice').text();
        console.log(newPractice);
        save(bid, newWord, newDialogue, newPractice)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use `.text()` on input and textarea, in which case we would have to use the function `.val()`.

I noticed that you stored the field name but never used it so it would come in handy when trying to get the value of the field that is in edit mode.

Below is a working snippet

```js
$("table").on("click", "[data-editable]", function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.find("textarea").length)
      return;
    var str = $el.text();
    console.log(str);
    var $input = $('<textarea rows=5 style="width:500px"/>').val( str );
    $el.html($input);
    $input.focus();
    var field_name = $el.attr('data-name');
    var save = function(bid, newWord, newDialogue, newPractice){
        var $td = $input.val();
        $input.replaceWith($td);
        alert("saving bid: " + bid + ", newWord: " + newWord + ", newDialougue: " + newDialogue + ", newPractice: " + newPractice);
    };
    $($input).blur(function(){
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var bid = row.find('td.bid').text();
        var newWord = field_name == "word" ? row.find("td.word textarea").val() : row.find('td.word').text();
        var newDialogue = field_name == "dialogue" ? row.find("td.dialogue textarea").val() : row.find('td.dialogue').text();
        var newPractice = field_name == "practice" ? row.find("td.practice textarea").val() : row.find('td.practice').text(); 
        save(bid, newWord, newDialogue, newPractice)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="btable" class="bg-light table table-hover">
    <th class= "text-center">No</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Word</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Dialogue</th>
    <th class= "text-center">Practice</th>
    <tr>
        <td class="bid" data-name="bid">100</td>
        <td class="word" data-name="word" data-editable>word 1</td>
        <td class="dialogue" data-name="dialogue" data-editable>dialogue 1</td>
        <td class="practice" data-name="practice" data-editable>practice 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="bid" data-name="bid">200</td>
        <td class="word" data-name="word" data-editable>word 2</td>
        <td class="dialogue" data-name="dialogue" data-editable>dialogue 2</td>
        <td class="practice" data-name="practice" data-editable>practice 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks Ive been working around somewhere around your answer, but I found the same problem goes here too. It's when I click twice in edit mode, the data in the box all disappears.

Comment: oh right, I'm editing the snippet to do the extra checking

Comment: updated by checking if there is already a textarea in the `data-editable` field

Comment: I couldn't have thought checking the length of textarea. What an easy way thanks.